# Incorrect spacing in description environments within (nested) multicols environments

Tags: spacing, multicol, alignment, description

I am trying to put a `description` environment inside the `multicol` package's multicols environment. The goal is to create two columns (the second of which is subdivided into two more columns) to display the SI units and their prefixes:

```latex
\begin{multicols}{2}
    {\centering\textbf{Units}\par}
    \begin{description}
        \item[s] second, time
        \item[m] meter, length
        \item[kg] kilogram, mass
        \item[A] ampere, electric current
        \item[K] kelvin, thermodynamic temperature
        \item[mol] mole, amount of substance
        \item[cd] candela, luminous intensity
    \end{description}
    \columnbreak
    
    {\centering\textbf{Prefixes}\par}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{description}
            \item[da] deca, $10^{1}$
            \item[h] hecto, $10^{2}$
            \item[k] kilo, $10^{3}$
            \item[M] mega, $10^{6}$
            \item[G] giga, $10^{9}$
            \item[T] tera, $10^{12}$
            \item[P] peta, $10^{15}$
            \item[E] exa, $10^{18}$
            \item[Z] zetta, $10^{21}$
            \item[Y] yotta, $10^{24}$
            \item[R] ronna, $10^{27}$
            \item[Q] quetta, $10^{30}$
        \end{description}
        \columnbreak
        
        \begin{description}
            \item[d] deci, $10^{-1}$
            \item[c] centi, $10^{-2}$
            \item[m] milli, $10^{-3}$
            \item[\textmu] micro, $10^{-6}$ % `\textmu` is from the `textgreek` package
            \item[n] nano, $10^{-9}$
            \item[p] pico, $10^{-12}$
            \item[f] femto, $10^{-15}$
            \item[a] atto, $10^{-18}$
            \item[z] zepto, $10^{-21}$
            \item[y] yocto, $10^{-24}$
            \item[r] ronto, $10^{-27}$
            \item[q] quecto, $10^{-30}$
        \end{description}
        
    \end{multicols}
\end{multicols}
```

I want the spacing between items in all of the `description` environments to be equal, and I want the prefixes in the two sub-columns of the second column to align with one another (i.e., "deca" to "deci," "hecto" to "centi," "kilo" to "milli," etc.). However, I am ending up with this:
[image: Illustration of the uneven spacing between list items]
There is more spacing between the items in the left column (the units), and the prefixes in the right column are not properly aligned.

**Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: multicol* will  not attempt to balance the columns.  This will give you equal spacing, but the firat column will fill the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a table, not a `description`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}ll@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\bfseries Units} \\
s   &  second, time \\
m   &  meter, length \\
kg  &  kilogram, mass \\
A   &  ampere, electric current \\
K   &  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}kelvin, thermodynamic \\ temperature \end{tabular} \\
mol &  mole, amount of substance \\
cd  &  candela, luminous intensity
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}ll@{\qquad}>{\bfseries}ll@{}}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\bfseries Prefixes} \\
da &  deca, $10^{1}$    &     d &  deci, $10^{-1}$ \\
h  &  hecto, $10^{2}$   &     c &  centi, $10^{-2}$ \\
k  &  kilo, $10^{3}$    &     m &  milli, $10^{-3}$ \\
M  &  mega, $10^{6}$    &     \textmu &  micro, $10^{-6}$ \\
G  &  giga, $10^{9}$    &     n &  nano, $10^{-9}$ \\
T  &  tera, $10^{12}$   &     p &  pico, $10^{-12}$ \\
P  &  peta, $10^{15}$   &     f &  femto, $10^{-15}$ \\
E  &  exa, $10^{18}$    &     a &  atto, $10^{-18}$ \\
Z  &  zetta, $10^{21}$  &     z &  zepto, $10^{-21}$ \\
Y  &  yotta, $10^{24}$  &     y &  yocto, $10^{-24}$ \\
R  &  ronna, $10^{27}$  &     r &  ronto, $10^{-27}$ \\
Q  &  quetta, $10^{30}$ &     q &  quecto, $10^{-30}$
\end{tabular}

\caption{Units and prefixes of the International System}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]